# Wordpress - site_url() returns with additional backslashes

Tags: php, wordpress, escaping

I am using `site_url()` function and it returns the address as `http:\/\/vip.local\/cc` where I can see that WP automatically adds unnecessary backslashes. Is this for some escaping purpose? I tried using `stripslashes` function but that didn't fix it either. Any help?

Comment: Try using [`get_site_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_url) instead of just `site_url()`.

Comment: Tried. Even with stripslashes. No luck

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`stripslashes([string])`](http://php.net/stripslashes).

This removes all backslashes (required they need to be) from the given string.

**Edit**

Code I tested with: [PHPaste Snippet](https://phpaste.ga/paste/78a844).

**Edit 2**

Code is being used with [`json_encode([array])`](http://php.net/json_encode), automatically adding slashes.

Comment: @ChaniLastnamé please show me how you used it. **Edit** I also added a snippet in my OP as to how I tested it.

Comment: `$stats['site-url'] = stripslashes( site_url() );`

Comment: Do that, and right under it put `die($stats['site-url']);`.

Comment: That did it. but what is going on?

Comment: How are you using the site_url() thing? Maybe where ever you are using it has another function with `addslashes()` inside of it.

Comment: I am passing that $stats array to json_encode function. Does that add slashes?

Comment: Yes. It's so that nothing goes wrong in the JSON syntax.

Comment: Anyway to avoid that?

Comment: Nope, it's just part of the JSON syntax. Whoever is picking up the JSON has to parse it and that will in turn remove the slashes.